# Rotate Prefab based on camera direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a Rollercoaster-Tycoon clone in Unity, and have run into the issue of how to position tracks. I want the track to have an offset from the last placed track based on the direction of the camera. I tried using a `Vector3` to offset the track, but that vector would only work for that specific direction. I need it to offset the track based on the direction the player is building in. (The camera's direction) What is a quick and simple fix for this issue?

Comment: get `Vector3` from the current camera and use that vector?

Comment: I could, but that would place the track in the same place. I need to offset the track however many units forward based on the camera's direction.

Comment: @LandedBarker I am lost since you do not show any code. You take the transform position of the last track tile or whatever the element is, add to it the X or Y or whichever dimension of the next track tile and then rotate it to the angle of the current camera. Or at least that's what I would try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use the [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) method to determine the rotation of the camera, and apply that to the new track piece.

```
Vector3 offset = camera.transform.forward * offsetDistance;
Vector3 newTrackPosition = lastTrackPosition + offset;
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(camera.transform.forward);
newTrack.transform.position = newTrackPosition;
newTrack.transform.rotation = rotation;
```